Can an irrep become reducible on multiplication by a 1 dimensional irrep?
My background is in physics, and I am learning a little bit of representation theory of finite groups (with matrices over the field of complex numbers; this will be the setting for my question).  Usually when I think about tensor products of irreducible representations, I imagine that the irreps are multi-dimensional and their tensor product can be decomposed into a direct sum of irreps.
I am trying to understand what happens when one of the two irreps in my tensor product is one-dimensional, and how much that constrains what I see in the decomposition of the tensor product into irreps.
In particular, can such a tensor product be reducible?

I've checked the simplest nontrivial example of $S_3$, and the tensor product of the sign representation with the two-dimensional irrep is equivalent under similarity transformation to the two-dimensional irrep, and the other cases are trivial. That is, for this group, all tensor products of a one-dimensional irrep with any other irrep are themselves irreducible.
Similarly, for $D_4$, the choice of 2d representation to have rotation $r = -i \sigma^y$ and reflection $s=\sigma^x$ in terms of Pauli matrices naturally allows the tensor products of any 1d rep with this 2d rep to be equivalent under similarity transformation by a Pauli matrix to the 2d representation.
Is there an example where the tensor product of a 1d irrep with some other irrep is reducible?

The tensor product $V \otimes I$ of an irreducible representation and a $1$-dimensional representation is always again irreducible.
This is because tensoring with $I$ establishes a bijection between invariant subspaces of $V$ and invariant subspaces of $V \otimes I$, where the inverse of the bijection is given by tensoring with the dual $I^{\ast}$, so if $V \otimes I$ had a proper nonzero invariant subspace then tensoring with $I^{\ast}$ would give a proper nonzero invariant subspace of $V$.

 A comment for lovers of abstraction which can be safely skipped. The abstract form of this argument is that a $1$-dimensional representation $I$ is exactly a representation which is invertible with respect to the tensor product, with inverse the dual $I^{\ast}$ as above. This means that the functor $(-) \otimes I$ is an equivalence of categories, so it preserves all categorical properties, and simplicity is a categorical property. This can be thought of as a categorification of the familiar statement that the product of an irreducible element of a ring and an invertible element is another irreducible. This argument is extremely general and implies, for example, that objects $I$ invertible with respect to the tensor product (such as line bundles in algebraic geometry) have every categorical property possessed by the monoidal unit.


My guesstimate is that this is the most elegant argument. It is also possible to prove the same claim by verifying the required identity of inner products of characters (in the case of finite groups and their complex reps). Somehow I find that less satisfying :-)

@Jyrki: well, that argument is fine but it only applies to finite-dimensional representations of finite groups. This argument applies in e.g. the category of modules over an arbitrary commutative ring, infinite-dimensional representations of arbitrary groups and Lie algebras, etc. Also even in the finite group case it does not depend on any development of character theory. It can even be phrased without the dual, really.
